# Sequelize hasMany association issue

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

In my application a user can have several `module` which is stored in the `user_has_module` table. This means that for each `user_has_module` row, I want to include `module` where the `module_id` matches.

**module**

```
Module = sequelize.define('module', {
    academy_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    module_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    module_module_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    score_to_pass: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true
    })
```

**user_has_module**

```
User_has_module = sequelize.define('user_has_module', {
     user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
     },
     module_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
     },
     academy_team_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
     },
     academy_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
     },
     sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     is_complete: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     score_to_pass: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     is_open: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     deadline: DataTypes.DATE
}, {
   freezeTableName: true
})
```

**My relation**

```
User_has_module.belongsTo(Module, {foreignKey: 'module_id'});
```

Now what I want to do is join them on `module.module_id = user_has_module.module_id`.

My problem is that `module` has, as you can see, two `primary key`, and when sequelize joins these two tables, it chooses `academy_id` as its `primary key`.

My question is, is there a way to tell `Sequelize` that in this relation it has to choose the `primary key` `module_id` from `module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a model called User_has_module.
I assume you have one model called User and one model call Module.

So you should have designed something like this:

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                User.hasMany(models.Module);
            }
        }
    });
```

And for your Module:

```
var Module = sequelize.define("Module", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Module.belongsToMany(models.User);
            }
        }
    });
```

To get a User with its Modules you can do this:

```
models.User.findAll({ include: [models.Module]}).then(function(users){
        console.log(users);
    });
```

Hope I got your question right and it helps.
Cheers